# XML Memory leak with valgrind in xmlSaveFormatFileEnc using libxml2

Tags: xml, memory-leaks, valgrind, libxml2

I ve written a module to dump some real time data into an XML file at
regular intervals.
I am using  xmlSaveFormatFileEnc( ) finaly to save the file.

But i am getting memory leak report with the Valgrind with the API
xmlSaveFormatFileEnc( ).

The leak summary is as below,

```
==8355== 261,507,768 bytes in 506,798 blocks are definitely lost in los s
record 109 of 109
==8355==    at 0x402BE68: malloc (in
/usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-x86-linux.so)
==8355==    by 0x40E43FB: xmlGetGlobalState (in
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.7.8)
==8355==    by 0x40E3A22: __xmlIndentTreeOutput (in
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.7.8)
==8355==    by 0x414BE54: ??? (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.7.8)
==8355==    by 0x414C598: ??? (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.7.8)
==8355==    by 0x414BE42: ??? (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.7.8)
==8355==    by 0x414C598: ??? (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.7.8)
==8355==    by 0x414BE42: ??? (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.7.8)
==8355==    by 0x414C598: ??? (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.7.8)
==8355==    by 0x414BE42: ??? (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.7.8)
==8355==    by 0x414C598: ??? (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.7.8)
==8355==    by 0x414BE42: ??? (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.7.8)
==8355==    by 0x414C598: ??? (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.7.8)
==8355==    by 0x414BE42: ??? (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.7.8)
==8355==    by 0x414B8B7: ??? (in /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.7.8)
==8355==    by 0x414D339: xmlSaveFormatFileEnc (in
/usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/libxml2.so.2.7.8)
==8355==    by 0x805D5F0: store_to_xmlfile(char*, char*)
(ram_utilities.cpp:248)
==8355==    by 0x805D3E1: FetchDataFromFifo() (ram_utilities.cpp:198)
==8355==    by 0x8050A5D: ThreadFn_RqstAnlysr(void*)
(request_analyser_module.cpp:134)
==8355==    by 0x42FDD4B: start_thread (pthread_create.c:308)
==8355==
```

Please suggest me the measures to avoid memory leaks.

I have also added xmlinitparser() and xmlCleanupParser() to my code but the memory-leak has not stopped.

the code for storing to xml is as below...

```
void addxmldata(xmlDocPtr , xmlNodePtr , struct Res_Am_Snr_Body *);
void add_hr_dt(xmlNodePtr , struct Res_Am_Snr_Body *);
void add_min_dt(xmlNodePtr , struct Res_Am_Snr_Body *);
void add_snr_data(xmlNodePtr , struct Res_Am_Snr_Body *);

int store_to_xmlfile(char* msgbuf, char* xmlfile)
{
        int ret_val;
        xmlDocPtr doc = NULL;
        xmlNodePtr root_node = NULL;

        xmlInitParser();
        printf("In store_to_xmlfilexml file--->%s\n", xmlfile);

        doc = xmlParseFile(xmlfile);

        if(doc == NULL)
        {
                cout<<"failed to open-->"<<xmlfile<<endl;
        }

        root_node = xmlDocGetRootElement(doc);

        addxmldata(doc, root_node, msgbuf);

        cout<<"in store_to_xmlfile return"<<endl;

        ret_val = xmlSaveFormatFileEnc(xmlfile, doc, "UTF-8", 1);

        xmlFreeDoc(doc);

        xmlCleanupParser();

        return ret_val;
```

}

I'm calling addxmldata which in turn calls addhr, min and snr at tat perticular interval of time.

The xml file is perfectly built but there is lot of memory leak. My program is supposed to run continuously but crashes after one and half an hour. The memory leak in valgrind is almost 2 gb. the valgrind report shows repeated entry of the above error.

Plz help me out as i'm new to valgrind usage.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to remove the call to `xmlCleanupParser`. The [documentation](http://xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-parser.html#xmlCleanupParser) says:

> This function name is somewhat misleading. It does not clean up parser state, it cleans up memory allocated by the library itself. It is a cleanup function for the XML library. It tries to reclaim all related global memory allocated for the library processing. It doesn't deallocate any document related memory. One should call xmlCleanupParser() only when the process has finished using the library and all XML/HTML documents built with it. See also xmlInitParser() which has the opposite function of preparing the library for operations. WARNING: if your application is multithreaded or has plugin support calling this may crash the application if another thread or a plugin is still using libxml2. It's sometimes very hard to guess if libxml2 is in use in the application, some libraries or plugins may use it without notice. In case of doubt abstain from calling this function or do it just before calling exit() to avoid leak reports from valgrind !

Note the last sentence. `xmlCleanupParser` should only be called right before exiting a process.

Comment: I guess 2 years is not **soon** enough.